# Replace subquery with appropriate join

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join

how can i remove subquery with a join?

```
SELECT distinct t."groupId" FROM "contacts" c 
        INNER JOIN
        ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT td.* FROM "groups" g
        INNER JOIN 
        "territory" td 
        ON 
        td."groupId" = g.id
        WHERE g."orgId" = 3
        ) 
        t
        ON 
        ST_Intersects(t.points, c."geoPoint")
        WHERE c.id = 33 and c."orgId" = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with a subquery, but you should get rid of the dreaded `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT td."groupId"
FROM territory AS td
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM contacts AS c
              WHERE ST_Intersects(td.points, c."geoPoint")
                AND c.id = 33
                AND c."orgId" = 3)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM groups AS g
              WHERE td."groupId" = g.id
                AND g."orgId" = 3);
```

If you insist in having no subqueries, use

```
SELECT DISTINCT t."groupId"
   FROM contacts c 
      INNER JOIN territory td 
         ON ST_Intersects(td.points, c."geoPoint")
      INNER JOIN groups g
         ON td."groupId" = g.id
WHERE g."orgId" = 3
  AND c.id = 33
  AND c."orgId" = 3;
```

If you need to make sure that the `st_intersects` function is only called for rows from `territory` that match the join with `groups`, you will have to use a subquery. There is no other way to force a join order.

Comment: client wants no subquery at all.. :/

Comment: Silly requirement. I have added an alternative.

Comment: actually i want to st_intersect only on those td(territories) that satisfies the td.groupid = g.id join, basically use the territories returned by second join into st_intersect join

Comment: That's what you will get.

Comment: the query i posted is working but this is not :/  `Unable to generate outside point!` is the error. with your query its intersecting with every territory regardless of second join

Comment: Then my update to the answer will answer your question. You will have to use a subquery.

Comment: i guess ur right.. thnku so much for that distinct's suggestion :)

Comment: `DISTINCT` is always a red flag for my clients.